# Capture the onclick event on DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Can anybody knows how to capture the onclick event on DialogFragment. I need to reset the time if user click on the Dialog (CustomDialog which extends DialogFragment).

Thanks
Mindus

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12623683/996493) might helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i need to capture the event where ever i click on the dialog, not only on dialog buttons.

Comment: Then instead of onClick, you should try onTouch