# how to implement Dialog using DialogFragement?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I am developing android apps in that i want to develop dialog using SherlockDialogFragment for support all version of the android and this dialog having 4 edittext so user can fill the data and submit it,so my dialog is like following image.1

**dialog-**

[image]

I am already used Dialog class but i don't want to use Dialog. I want to implement DialogFragment for supporting multiple screens as per resolution. i googled but i don't understand how to use Dialogfragment.
 please anybody suggest me some answer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the thing you don't understand? Have you read [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.ro/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html)

Comment: How to return string from this DialogFragment to Activity from where this DialogFragment was called?

Comment: public class KeepOnHoldDialog extends DialogFragment{

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
   Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View  view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_onhold, container);
   getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                 LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
  return view;
 } }
<br />"Encountered exeception like" :
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity 

ComponentInfo{com.ojaswitech.bookinscape/com.ex.bs.KeepOnHoldDialog}: java.lang.ClassCastException: 

com.ex.bs.KeepOnHoldDialog

Comment: google it a bit, for example [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905312/receive-result-from-dialogfragment) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622742/get-value-from-dialogfragment)