# Create menu from button?

Tags: android

I would like to create menu where I can select how to sort posts. On iOS exists something like this:
[image: my app]

It's something similiar on Android? Or can give me advice which component I should use to solve my task?
My app:[image]

Comment: It's a [Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html). With a ListView inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today the best way is create a dialog fragment where you can inflate it with differents layouts, in your case different menus. [In this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30799391/3996257) I talk a little about Dialog Fragment and I show a simple example.

Tell me if I helped you and good programming!!

Comment: Thanks, I used that link inside and solved my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Its action sheet in iOS. Follow this https://movivations.wordpress.com/2012/05/07/implementing-ios-actionsheet-in-android/ to make action sheet in android.