# DialogFragment vs MessageBox

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I am new to Android and am having difficult times handling a very simple task.  I understand that in Android, a DialogFragment is non-blocking programmatically.  I have my DialogFragment with positive and negative buttons on it and I am calling it from activity that is set as listener for this DialogFragment.  That is all fine.

The problem I am having is that in C#, I would use a MessageBox which allows me to check what user has choosen (Yes or No).  So, I could write something like this

```
public void DoSomething(){
  if (boolA == false){
    if (MessageBox.Show(....) == mbYes){
      DoTask();
    }
  }
  else {
    DoTask();
  }
}
```

In C#, the execution would stop at MessageBox.Show().  But in Android, that is not the case.  Also, in C#, I know how to get result of the MessageBox.Show (Yes or No) but I dont know how do I do that in Android.

So, I am trying to use DialogFragment to make decision what to do next.  How do I do that?  Please provide example as I am novice to Android.

Much appreciated

Comment: You need to pass a reference to something that you want to operate on, and then just call some method on that reference, like a callback. You need to provide more detail for a more comprehensive answer. Some code you have written for example.

Comment: I think this link can help. 
http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/pop-ups/

Comment: You can't get the result synchronously. When you block main thread you will get Application not responding message. See that link what have i posted earlier. I hope it can help you.

Comment: Thanks krystian71115.  I am not using C#.  I am developing in Java for Android.  I am refering to C# just to explain my point.  Much appreciated.

Comment: See this tutorial.http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-dialogfragment-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

You can build a simple AlertDialog

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setTitle("My Title")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                     //DoSomething
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                     //DO something
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alertDialog=builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: That's not really answering the question, on how to use a `DialogFragment`.

Comment: Yes but it can be use in place of it it can do the same thing that DialogFragment can do ,

Comment: Not exactly the same. Pop up your `AlertDialog`, rotate the phone, dialog gone.

Comment: Ok I didn't know that ,Thanks for this,Can you tell me difference between AlertDialog and DialogFragment

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977392/android-dialogfragment-vs-dialog

Comment: Sorry but I am not looking into solution how to create and show AlertDialog or DialogFragment.  That I know.  My question is asking how to use DialogFragment to make decision in execution flow.

Comment: @dbnex14 When yes or no is clicked onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) is called and in that methods you can do something.

Comment: MyBad  maybe this can help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622742/get-value-from-dialogfragment)